# How to create result set from Linq with enumerable types?

Tags: c#, linq

The result set below:

```
ServiceName                                     Ping                                                         Desc                       LogName                                         BaseUrl                          EnvName         
IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsService /IntegrationServices/BillingInstructionsService.svc/Rest/Ping BillingInstructionsService IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsServices https://icrDev.xxx.com   Dev 
IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsService /IntegrationServices/BillingInstructionsService.svc/Rest/Ping BillingInstructionsService IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsServices https://IUTD01.xxx.com   DevUnitTest 
IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsService /IntegrationServices/BillingInstructionsService.svc/Rest/Ping BillingInstructionsService IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsServices https://ickd01.xxx.com    DevClock 
IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsService /IntegrationServices/BillingInstructionsService.svc/Rest/Ping BillingInstructionsService IntegrationServices.BillingInstructionsServices https://icd01.xxx.com     DevConv
```

is returned from the linq query below my needs can be either filtered(ServiceId) or unfiltered ...:

```
var data = contextObj.ServiceMonitorMappings
            .Where(r => r.ServiceId == 33)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ServiceName = x.Service.Name,
                Ping = x.Service.PingUrl,
                Desc = x.Service.Description,
                LogName = x.ServiceLoggingName.LoggingName,
                BaseUrl = x.ServiceBaseUrl.ServiceBaseUrl1,
                EnvName = x.ServiceEnvironment.Name
            });
```

ServiceMonitorMapping looks like this:

```
public partial class ServiceMonitorMapping
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ServiceEnvironmentId { get; set; }
public int ServiceId { get; set; }
public int ServiceLoggingNameId { get; set; }
public int ServiceBaseUrlId { get; set; }

public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
public virtual ServiceLoggingName ServiceLoggingName { get; set; }
public virtual ServiceBaseUrl ServiceBaseUrl { get; set; }
public virtual ServiceEnvironment ServiceEnvironment { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to get BaseUrl and EnvName to return as an enumerable collection so that I wouldn't have 4 records but 1 with the last 2 columns containing a list of BaseUrl and EnvName, however I cannot find a way to do this. So I am stuck with 4 records as opposed to 1.  Does not seem to be ideal to me.

So my question is this, is it possible to return just 1 row with the last 2 columns being a collection so that I have "item item item item List<> List<>"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it sounds like you want GroupBy,  take a look and if you can't figure it out I'll post an example

Comment: ah... I had not thought about groupby ... I will take a look! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = contextObj.ServiceMonitorMappings
            .Where(r => r.ServiceId == 33)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Key = new {ServiceName = x.Service.Name,
                           Ping = x.Service.PingUrl,
                           Desc = x.Service.Description,
                           LogName = x.ServiceLoggingName.LoggingName};
                BaseUrl = x.ServiceBaseUrl.ServiceBaseUrl1,
                EnvName = x.ServiceEnvironment.Name
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
            .Select(g => new
            {
              ServiceName = g.Key.ServiceName,
              Ping = g.Key.Ping,
              Desc = g.Key.Desc,
              LogName = g.Key.LogName,
              BaseUrls = g.Select(x => x.BaseUrl).ToList(),
              EnvNames = g.Select(x => x.EnvName ).ToList();
            })
```

Comment: That works!  I just started looking into how to do this... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Although tolanj's answer is rather good, I believe it is not the easiest approach. You could use just `Select` after grouping to simplify your query:

```
var data = contextObj.ServiceMonitorMappings
            .GroupBy(r => r.ServiceId)
            .Where(r => r.Key == 33)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ServiceName = x.First().Service.Name,
                Ping = x.First().Service.PingUrl,
                Desc = x.First().Service.Description,
                LogName = x.First().ServiceLoggingName.LoggingName,
                BaseUrl = x.Select(y => y.ServiceBaseUrl.ServiceBaseUrl1).ToList(), //ToList is optional
                EnvName = x.Select(y => y.ServiceEnvironment.Name).ToList() //ToList is optional
            });
```

At first, I didn't notice that this is a DB query through LINQ to SQL. In order to use this approach and not loose the performance due to downloading whole table you can try it like this:

```
var data = contextObj.ServiceMonitorMappings
            .Where(r => r.ServiceId == 33)
            .AsEnumerable()  //AsEnumerable after Where to apply filter on the DB query
            .GroupBy(x => 1) //data already filtered, only one group as a result
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ServiceName = x.First().Service.Name,
                Ping = x.First().Service.PingUrl,
                Desc = x.First().Service.Description,
                LogName = x.First().ServiceLoggingName.LoggingName,
                BaseUrl = x.Select(y => y.ServiceBaseUrl.ServiceBaseUrl1).ToList(), //ToList is optional
                EnvName = x.Select(y => y.ServiceEnvironment.Name).ToList() //ToList is optional
            });
```

Comment: Just tested your answer and I get an error "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead"  Changing the 'First' to FirstOrDefault then generates another error "ArgumentException: DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType."

Comment: this looks like issues with "LINQ to SQL" try calling [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or `ToList` before `GroupBy`

Comment: adding 'AsEnumerable' sort of helped but the selectmany creates a result of IEnumerable<Char> not string. so each letter is its own element in the list.

Comment: @Kixoka, it seems like I tried too hard. Simple `Select` does it (corrrected answer). On the other hand, you could try to profile which of current solutions is faster, as LINQ to SQL can optimize well in certain scenarios, while not at all in others - it also depends on the size of your data

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you understand your needs; I solved with this way:

```
var query = contextObj.ServiceMonitorMappings
    .Where(r => r.ServiceId == 33)
    .Select(d => new { 
                 BaseUrl = d.ServiceBaseUrl.ServiceBaseUrl1, 
                 EnvName = d.ServiceEnvironment.Name})
    .Aggregate((d1, d2) =>
    new {
        BaseUrl = d1.BaseUrl + ", " + d2.BaseUrl,
        EnvName = d1.EnvName + ", " + d2.EnvName
    });
```

This is the result:

```
BaseUrl
https://icrDev.xxx.com, https://IUTD01.xxx.com, https://ickd01.xxx.co, https://icd01.xxx.com 
EnvName 
Dev, DevUnitTest, DevClock, DevConv
```

**EDIT**:

I've changed my query to return your needed result:

```
var query = contextObj.ServiceMonitorMappings
    .Where(r => r.ServiceId == 33)
    .Select(d => new { 
                 BaseUrl = d.ServiceBaseUrl.ServiceBaseUrl1, 
                 EnvName = d.ServiceEnvironment.Name})
        .Aggregate(
            //initialize the accumulator
            new { BaseUrl = new List<string>(), EnvName = new List<string>() }, 
            (acc, next) => //accumulator and nextItem
            {
                acc.BaseUrl.Add(next.BaseUrl);
                acc.EnvName.Add(next.EnvName);
                return acc;
            });
```

Comment: That's not quite what I needed, but I like how you did it. thank you!

Comment: @Kixoka: now my query returns one record with two list :)